# I need to connect to a local site from the emulator, not localhost though

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, virtualbox

Ok, I've been searching for an hour and I think the keywords are making it impossible to find the answer specific to my situation.  Here's how I'm setup:

1) I have several local websites under development on my local machine using vagrant and virtual box.

2) each site has it's own ip/domain in my hosts file, so I access them like http://www.example.com

3) I'm developing an android app that uses a backend api, and I need it to access one of my local sites.

The problem is that all the answers I find say to use 10.0.2.2 from the emulator to access the local machine, but my sites aren't located at http://localhost. which is basically where that points.

how do I access a local(on my host machine) virtualbox (where my site is located) from my running android emulator.

notes: I'm on a macbook pro, using android studio 2.1.2 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add your local server's ip and domain to emulaor's hosts file.

Here is tutorial.
http://borkweb.com/story/setting-etchosts-on-an-android-emulator-using-a-mac